# Checking database's username and data if they match the user info or not

Tags: mysql, sql, database, tomcat, xampp

I want to check that the username and data which is already in database is match with the user info or not. I have written some code but it doesn't select a row.

Here is my code:

```
public boolean iscorrect(String name , String pass){

    boolean check=false;

    openConnection();
    Statement st =null;
    ResultSet rs =  null;

    try{
        st = conn.createStatement();
        String q = "Select * from signup where email = '"+name+"'" ;
        rs=st.executeQuery(q);
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"    "+rs.getString(2));
        if(rs.getString(1).equals(name) && rs.getString(2).equals(pass)){
            check = true;
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return check;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first call `rs.next()` to put the cursor at the first row of data. This will return `false` if there is no data.

In addition to that:

- please use PreparedStatement and bind variables to avoid SQL injection
- you could put the checks into the WHERE clause instead of loading the whole row
- please don't store clear text passwords, use a cryptographic hash function